# Computing a probability over a set of probability distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let
$$\Delta(\Omega_n) = \left\{\mathbf{p} : \Omega_n \to [0,1] \ \Bigg\vert \ \sum_{x \in \Omega_n} \mathbf{p}(x) = 1 \right\}
$$
be the set of all possible probability distributions defined over a countable and discrete domain $\Omega_n$ of cardinality $n$.

Now, given $\sigma_1, \sigma_2 \in \Omega_n$, with $\mathbf{p}(\sigma_1) > 0$, construct a *possibly biased coin* $\mathbf{q} : \{ H, T \} \to [0,1]$ as:
$$
\begin{cases}
\mathbf{q}(H) = \frac{\mathbf{p}(\sigma_1)}{\mathbf{p}(\sigma_1) + \mathbf{p}(\sigma_2)} \\
\mathbf{q}(T) = \frac{\mathbf{p}(\sigma_2)}{\mathbf{p}(\sigma_1) + \mathbf{p}(\sigma_2)}
\end{cases}
$$

I am interested in computing $\Pr \left[ \mathbf{q}(H) \geq 1/2 \right]$.

---

My intuition was that $\Pr \left[ \mathbf{q}(H) \geq 1/2 \right]$ represents the fraction of $H$-biased coins, among all possible coins.

A coin is just some $p \in [0, 1]$, so if we assume that we pick some $p \in [0,1]$ uniformly at random, we get:

$$
\begin{align}
\Pr[p\geq1/2] &= 1 - \Pr[p < 1/2]  \\
&= 1 - \mathsf{CDF}_{\mathsf{Uniform(0,1)}}(1/2) \\
&= 1-1/2 \\
&= 1/2
\end{align}
$$

But I think there is a flaw in this logic, namely because:
$$
\Pr[\mathbf{q}(H)\geq 1/2] \neq \Pr [p \geq 1/2]
$$
since there are infinitely many ways of constructing $\mathbf{q}(H)$ to have a fixed value.

Is this right?

Comment: The set of probabilities you have listed is uncountably infinite, so there is no natural probability for us to compute the probability you are describing.

Comment: I rephrased the problem and added my intuition.